# How to present modal view from UIPopoverController?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have this:

[image]

And have this, when presenting modally:

[image]

Some code jsut before presenting webview:

```
webViewController.modalInPopover = YES;
webViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

And have this in webViewController's viewDidLoad template:

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 436.0);
```

I've looked for every frame of every role playing view, but frame.sizes are correct.
Anybody with similar experience with a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I assigned a transistion style to presentation style.
And that was the enum for fullscreen.

Having this in webViewController init...

```
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

...solved the problem.

I'll try to move it to -(void)awakeFromNib; to get rid of hardcoded size.